# Detect client is disconnected

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a simple program that listens to a socket. Everything goes fine except when the connection is lost in `while(1)` cycle. In this case the program falls into read from socket for many times without result. How can I detect a disconnected client in `while(1)` cycle?

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


void printHex(char * bts  )
{
    char *s = bts;
    int i=0;
    do
    {
        printf("%02X ", (unsigned char  ) *bts);

    } while (* ++bts !=0);
    printf("%s\n",s);

}


int main()
{
    char str[100];
    int listen_fd, comm_fd;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    bzero( &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(22000);
    printf("binding\n");

    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));

    printf("listening\n");

    listen(listen_fd, 10);
    printf("accepting\n");

    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);
    printf("accep done\n");

    int cn =0;

    while(1)
    {

        bzero( str, 100);
        printf("will read\n");
        int br= read(comm_fd,str,100);
        printf("read done\n");

        if (br>0)
        {
            printHex(str);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
    if (br>0)
    {
        printHex(str);
    }
```

To:

```
    if (br<=0) break;
    printHex(str);
```

Also, your code mishandles the case where the first byte is zero. And you can't avoid this case because TCP does not preserve application message boundaries. You should just pass `br` to `printHex` so it will know how many characters to print.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the result of your `read()`. If the connection is closed you'll get a return-code for that.

From the [manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html):

> On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.